# In GAE, Python requests, are they really processed in parallel?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine, parallel-processing

I have this configuration in the module.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: F2
threadsafe: true

automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: 8
  min_pending_latency: 0.25s
  max_pending_latency: automatic
  max_concurrent_requests: 80
```

And in the Console I see numbers like these:

```
QPS*    Latency*    Requests    Errors  Age Memory  App Engine Rel. Availability
8.730   113.5 ms    12621         0    1:48:25  67.9 MBytes 1.9.27      Resident
14.142  76.7 ms     12543         0    1:48:26  79.8 MBytes 1.9.27      Resident    
13.411  74.3 ms     12753         0    1:48:26  96.4 MBytes 1.9.27      Resident
```

if you multiply the QPS (queries per second) by Latency (converted to seconds):

- 8.730  Queries/second x 0.1135 second = 0.990855 Queries
- 14.142 Queries/second x 0.0767 second = 1.0846914 Queries
- 13.411 Queries/second x 0.0743 second = 0.9964673 Queries

I repeated the same exercise many times a day and in all the case the final number at the right is very very close TO 1 query.

So I have my doubts if the same instance is capable to process queries in parallel. My processes as you can see in the average latency are very quick and when I need to do a long work the process uses taskqueues. I don't use async processes inside this module.  I read that when you have an idle process waiting for a urlfetch response, it will be a chance to another python thread/request execute in parallel, but is not my case.

The official documentation is not detailed in this area, just states this:

> Using concurrent requests
>
> By default, App Engine sends requests serially to a given web server. You can  configure App Engine to send multiple, parallel requests by adding the threadsafe element to app.yaml.
>
> threadsafe: true

Do I need to set another parameter or use a special library to allow many request be executed in parallel IN THE SAME INSTANCE? For the QPS numbers showed above the average CPU utilization is between 15% an 25% so there is space to run at least 3 request in parallel (personal estimation without enough analysis)

Thank you!

Comment: as far as I know, `threadsafe: true` is enough to tell GAE that the instance can handle multiple requests in parallel.  Note that with CPython, only 1 thread can be running at a time under most circumstances (due to limitations with the Global Interpreter Lock -- GIL).  So, in python, you don't usually gain much by threading unless the program is non-busy waiting -- e.g. if you spawned async requests to the datastore or using urlfetch.

Comment: Thank you, I read about this situaction also, for that reason I stated that my code in this module doesn't use async functions.  If I change the runtime to PHP or JAVA, will I have the same restrictions? If the PHP runtime could process request really in parallel, that could be a solution for me, I can migrate some modules to PHP.

Comment: A corollary of this would be that it is better to have more instances F1 than the equivalent amount of higher instances F2 or F4, as more request could be processed in parallel having more instances ... what do you think? Thinking in budget optimization when having thousands of QPS.

Comment: For python yes.  The other thing to consider. Threading in any language running on a single core cannot give you true parallel running.  Only one thread can run at a time. Where you win is when a thread is waiting on I/O  for instance, then other threads can be doing stuff.  That is one of the reasons async operations work so well. Each tasklet yields on I/O. In addition at the request level blocking on I/O  frees up time for each request to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

Using low latency requests is not a good indicator for app's multi-threading. A portion of processing the request happens in the GAE infra outside of the app itself (routing to the app, for example) or inside the app but in non-threaded areas. For low latency requests the non-threaded percentage can be significant, skewing the results and potentially leading to the wrong conclusion.

To check parallel request processing I'd suggest using high-latency requests which don't use potentially rate-limited GAE services. For example try making your request handlers do plain python processing or just sleep for 40-50 seconds before replying to see clearly if the requests really are processed in parallel or not.

Comment: Thank you Dan.  I found this video, very useful to clarify tis situation. https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=T_BQevqRp44#t=2094s   As a final thought, if my app is very low latency, it will be hard to take advantage of the multithreading due to few I/O operations leaving idle cpu time.